# Python OOP method call

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have 2 different classes:

> Automation and ClickElement

```
Window = Automation()
click_element = ClickElement()
```

In the class ClickElement is a method called 'by_span_name(name)'

Now i want to call the method in this way:

```
Window.click_element.by_span_name(name)
```

How do i do that?
If i try it like this way, Pycharm doesn´t suggest any class after the first dot of Window.click_elem... Does click_element have to inherit form Window?

Comment: If the method is in `ClickElement`, wouldnt it be `click_element.by_span_name(name)` ?

Comment: Yes, it´s right. But i want the structure like above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ClickElement as a [composed object](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/object-oriented-programming/classes-and-objects-ii-inheritance-and-composition/tutorial/) in Automation

```
Window = Automation()
Window.click_element = ClickElement()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Now it is working!